# How to rollapply() Maximum Likelihood Estimation in R

Tags: r, mle

I have a streamflow dataset `CFbasin2` with four variables 3768 rows, what I need to do is:

1. rolling linear regression in the dataset with 20 days window, first develop a regression from row 1 to row 20, then another regression from row 2 to row 21, then from row 3 to row 22, repeatedly doing this till the end and i can get a set of coefficient from each regression run.
2. Use Maximum Likelihood Estimation to optimize each set of parameter

| Qkl | Qhaw | Qdeep | Qlit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13.4 | 14.3 | 2.5 | 4.6 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

What I have done so far is:

1. I succesfully finished step 1, use `rollapply()` to repeatedly get all sets of coefficients.
2. tried to use `rollapply()` again with `mle2()` so that to repeatedly conduct MLE, but I failed in this step. I first wrote my negative likelihood function

```
regress.ll <- function(b0, b1, r0, r1, r2, b2, x = CFbasin2) {
  x1 = CFbasin2$Qhaw
  x2 = CFbasin2$Qdp
  x3 = CFbasin2$Qlit
  y = CFbasin2$Qkl
  y.hat = b0 + b1*(r0 + r1*x1 + r2*x2) + b2*x3
  errors = y - y.hat
  mu_error = mean(errors)
  sd_errors = sd(errors)
  neg.loklik = -sum(dnorm(errors, mean = mu_error, sd = sd_errors, log = T))
  return(neg.loklik)
}
```

then I try to use `rollapply()` again to conduct MLE and it doesn't work. I got an error says *"Error in validObject(.Object) :
invalid class “mle2” object: invalid object for slot "fullcoef" in class "mle2": got class "NULL", should be or extend class "numeric""*

```
rollapply(CFbasin2,
          width = 20,
          FUN = function(Z) {
            mle.results <- mle2(minuslogl = regress.ll, data = as.data.frame(Z),
                                start = list(b0 = dw_coef, b1 = dw_coef, r0 = up_coef, 
                                             r1 = up_coef, r2 = up_coef, b2 = dw_coef))
            return(mle.results)
          }, by.column=FALSE, align="right")
```

Any suggestion will be really appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Is this homework so you have to program it directly yourself or are you allowed to use external packages?

Comment: It is part of my mini-project in the class, and i need to do it in R. But if you have any other options, please also let me know!